# ClickOnce app install failure detail log location

Tags: windows, clickonce

In build automation, I want to be able to collect the detailed error log if the app fails to install. There is a little dialog box that says "Cannot Start Application". When I click the Details button, it opens a log. Where can I capture this log?

Answer (score 2):

By default the log is kept in user's temporary internet files, and is not easy to locate.

If you want it to be created in more convenient location of your choice, use regedit to add the `LogFilePath` setting under

```
HKEY_Current_User\Software\Classes\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Deployment\
```

The change will take effect immediately, without restart